# EF Code First approach never creates DB

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I used EF CF approach before and it worked perfectly. On another PC I am making MVC app and when I use CF approach, DB is never created. I'm not getting any exception, I don't know what to do.

Web config (not whole doc):

```xml
<connectionStrings>
   <add name = "DBSystemContext"
      connectionString = "server=LAPTOP-CNQSN67O\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=TestDB; Integrated Security=True" 
      providerName = "System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Context class:

```
public class DBSystemContext : DbContext
{
    public DBSystemContext() 
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Global.asax:

```
protected override void Seed(DBSystemContext context)
{
    Book b = new Book()
    {
        Name="Little Prince",
        Price=2323,
        Quantity=34
    };

    context.Books.Add(b);

    base.Seed(context);
}
```

Comment: Did you run db migration command ? And if you did is any error you get

Comment: I didn't. I read that problem may be resolved when I update VS, so now I'm updating it. Will post what happened after. @NgôHùngPhúc

Comment: If you dont run migration command so how can you get the database

Comment: I made DbContext and Seeder classes, I'm not that skilled in whole DB thing. I worked one with CF approach, followed tutorials and managed to make it work. Now on another project, I'm doing the same, but it simply doesn't get created @NgôHùngPhúc

Comment: @NgôHùngPhúc After update, I see this message: `AI: Diagnostic message: Performance counters are unavailable when the application is running under IIS Express. Use EnableIISExpressPerformanceCounters element with a value of 'true' within the Performance Collector Module element to override this behavior.`  Can u tell me what I need to run, what u meant by "migration command"?

Comment: @NgôHùngPhúc For some reason, when I had only seeder it didn't work, but when I added more entities manualy, DB was created.

Comment: please follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)